# How to get Listbox values in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have Two listboxes in view (**Note:Refer the attached Screenshot**).choose rounds(listbox1) and list of rounds(listbox2).I select and move my choices to second listbox.Now I need to get second list box values in controllers and insert that all selected values of second listbox into db.How to do this?

Model:

```
 public string[] listval { get; set; }
```

View:

```
<tr>
                <td align="right">
                    <p id="text" style="width: 90px;">Rounds</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ListBox("lstBox1", new List<SelectListItem>{ 
                     new SelectListItem() {Text = "--Choose Rounds--", Value="None"},
                     new SelectListItem() {Text = "GD", Value="GD"}, 
                     new SelectListItem() {Text = "Written", Value="Written"}, 
                     new SelectListItem() {Text = "Technical1", Value="Technical1"}, 
                     new SelectListItem() {Text = "Technical2", Value="Technical2"},
                     new SelectListItem() {Text = "HR", Value="HR"} 
                    })
                </td>
                <td style='width: 50px; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle;'>
                    <input type='button' id='btnRight' value='  >  ' />
                    <br />
                    <input type='button' id='btnLeft' value='  <  ' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ListBoxFor(m=>m.listval, new List<SelectListItem>{ new SelectListItem() {Text = "--List Of Rounds--"} })
                </td>
            </tr>


<script>
    $('#btnRight').click(function (e) {
        var selectedOpts = $('#lstBox1 option:selected');
        if (selectedOpts.length == 0) {
            alert("Nothing to move.");
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        $('#listval').append($(selectedOpts).clone());
        $(selectedOpts).remove();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#btnLeft').click(function (e) {
        var selectedOpts = $('#listval option:selected');
        if (selectedOpts.length == 0) {
            alert("Nothing to move.");
            e.preventDefault();
        }

        $('#lstBox1').append($(selectedOpts).clone());
        $(selectedOpts).remove();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

[image: Refer View]

Comment: @V V - When you submit the contents of the list box what should happen?  Do you want to submit the values using an ajax request so that the user is able to remain on the current web page or would you like to submit the values and perform a redirect to a completely different web page?

Comment: @Dangerous I submit the values by using FormMethod.Post

Comment: please refer this link that will help you.  http://vivekcek.wordpress.com/2014/02/26/passing-all-the-values-including-unselected-of-a-list-box-to-mvc-controller/

Answer (score 1):

### Try below script

> ```
>    <script>
>    $('#btnRight').click(function (e) {
>    var selectedOpts = $('#lstBox1 option:selected');
>    if (selectedOpts.length == 0) {
>    alert("Nothing to move.");
>    e.preventDefault();        }
>    $('#listval').append($(selectedOpts).clone());
>    $(selectedOpts).remove();
>    SelectList();
>    e.preventDefault(); });
>    $('#btnLeft').click(function (e) {
>    var selectedOpts = $('#listval option:selected');
>    if (selectedOpts.length == 0) {
>        alert("Nothing to move.");
>        e.preventDefault();
>    }
>
>   $('#lstBox1').append($(selectedOpts).clone());
>   $(selectedOpts).remove();
>    SelectList();
>   e.preventDefault();
>   });
>   //Here I am using SelectList() function to select options..of second listbox
>   function SelectList() {
>   $("#listval option").each(
>   function (index, option) {
>                         //Store the option
>                         if (index != 0)
>                             $(option).attr("selected", "selected");
>                     }
>                );
>   }
>    </script>
> ```